# Haskell type error - Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type 'RE a'

Tags: haskell

So I have the following lines...

```
firstMatches :: RE a -> [a] 
firstMatches (a :+: b)
    | (matchEmpty a == True) = [a]
```

where matchEmpty is defined as...

```
matchEmpty :: RE a -> Bool

matchEmpty Empty =  True
matchEmpty (a :+: b)
    | matchEmpty a == False = False
    | matchEmpty b == False = False
    | otherwise = True
```

I'm getting the error "Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type 'RE a'"

I'm pretty sure I'm just not giving the correct argument for matchEmpty but I don't know what to do

```
matchEmpty a == False = False
```

RE is defined as

```
data RE a            -- regular expressions over an alphabet defined by 'a'
= Empty          -- empty regular expression
| Sym a          -- match the given symbol
| RE a :+: RE a  -- concatenation of two regular expressions
| RE a :|: RE a  -- choice between two regular expressions
| Rep (RE a)     -- zero or more repetitions of a regular expression
| Rep1 (RE a)    -- one or more repetitions of a regular expression
deriving (Show)
```

Comment: What library are you using? It looks like `matchEmpty` can only return `True` here.

Comment: What's the definition of `RE` and what's the whole error message? Which type was expected to be `a`, but was `RE a`? The type of `a` in `[a]`? If so, what are the operand types of `:+:`?

Comment: matchEmpty can only return True or False, if it returns False for a then I know a has a value and I want to return a list of that value. The point of firstMatches is to return a list of the first values that are possible from a given regular expression.

Comment: @sepp2k added definition of RE. Expected return type is RE a. List should have a list of type a. :+: is regex for concatenation of two types a

Comment: Can you please also post the full error message. "Expected return type is RE a." Of what? The declared return type of `firstMatches` is `[a]`, not `RE a`. "List should have a list of type a" Not sure what you're trying to say here. " :+: is regex for concatenation of two types a" Not according to your code. According to your code `:+:` takes two `RE a`s, not two `a`s.

Comment: @sepp2k  Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for firstMatches :: RE a -> [a]
          at Project.hs:29:17
    In the return type of a call of `firstMatches'
    In the expression: firstMatches a
    In the expression: [firstMatches a]

Comment: "In the expression: firstMatches a In the expression: [firstMatches a]" Those expressions don't seem to be part of the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code block has two things called `a`.  Here I replaced variables to avoid that duplication:

```
firstMatches :: RE r -> [r] 
firstMatches (a :+: b)
    | (matchEmpty a == True) = [a]
```

Making the same substitution in the error message:

> Couldn't match expected type 'r' with actual type [r].  'r' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for firstMatches :: RE r -> [r]

You have `a :: Re r`, and construct `[a] :: [RE r]`.  But the type signature says that `firstMatches` returns `[r]`.

1. Maybe your implementation is correct, and you intend `firstMatches :: RE r -> [RE r]
2. Maybe your type signature is correct.  One way to make the RHS match the type sig is `| (matchEmpty a == True) = []`.  This function that always returns the empty list isn't very useful, but there's no value of type `r` in scope that we can use.  Do you have other functions that take an `RE r` and give back an `r`?  Should `firstMatches` get another argument?